# Laravel ::pluck multiple columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to populate a blade format `<select>` tag.

I'm aware of the `Model::pluck('column1', 'column2')` method to populate a select tag.

But in my case, I have to concatenate two columns , and get the id. something like

`Model::pluck('column_1 && column_2', 'id')`

Is it possible like that ? If yes, what would be the proper syntax?

If not, what would be the best alternative then ?

Answer (score 39):

Best solution is to create [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) function into your model, let's assume if you want to get full name then you can do like this.

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

and you can easily get full name.

```
$users = User::where('id', 1)->get()->pluck('full_name', 'id');
```

Eloquent will call `getFullNameAttribute` function and get concatenated value.

Comment: Will try this one. Thank you !

Comment: This is a great idea, but Eloquent `pluck()` method will give you the `Column not found` error. You need to get the data first and then use Collection method `pluck()` (it's completely different method). So, the code will look like `Model::get(['column1', 'column2', 'id'])->pluck('columns', 'id')`, please fix this. Also, upvoted.

Comment: Alex, amazing and important note you said.

Comment: The mentioned documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) doesn't help in understanding this implementation. 
Use latest documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for better understanding..
Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin - i already know the given answer, what I am missing is your solution. upvoted!

Answer (score 6):

You could use `selectRaw()`:

```
Model::selectRaw("CONCAT ('column1', 'column2') as columns, id")->pluck('columns', 'id');
```

Or you could do this manually:

```
$collection = Model::get(['column1', 'column2', 'id']);
foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $plucked[$item->id] = $item->column1 . $item->column2;
}
dd($plucked);
```

Comment: Will try this one. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

Model results retrieved by the `get()` method are just children of the regular Support-Collection class, so you actually get access to all the same goodies.  Try this:

```
$eloquentCollection = app(YourModel::class)
    ->where('field', 'value')
    ->get(['id', 'column_1', 'column_2']);

$mapped = $eloquentCollection->mapWithKeys(function (YourModel $model) {
    return [$model->id => $model->column_1 . $model->column_2];
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way:

```
    return User::select(DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " - ", last_name) AS full_name, id'))
           ->pluck('full_name', 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so people who come here know, the pluck method returns an object, and if you want to pluck multiple columns and return an array at the same time without using the `toArray` method, you could just pass the names of the column to the `all()` function, and it will return the wanted columns as an array.

```
YourModelName::all('id', 'name');
```

Comment: Good suggestion but something to be noted; this returns an array and not a collection

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty late but you could do something like this:

`$data = Model::select('id','column_1','column_2')->get()`

and then use it inside blade like:

`$data->first_name." ".$data->last_name`

Answer (score 0):

You can select the columns of your choice with this:

```
YourModel::select('column1', 'columns2')->whereColumnId('1')->get()                                                                             
    ->map(function($model){
        return $model->column1.','.$model->column2;
    })->toArray();
```