# How to multiple show data in dropdown list . Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

I want to build multiple data showing in dropdown list like this

> Jhon-23 days
>
> Martin-23 days
>
> Marsha-19 days

so i Build on my controller like this

```
 public function input_cuti()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('roles_id',[1,3])->pluck('name_days','id');


    return view('admin.input.input_cuti',
    [
    'users'=>$users,


    ]);
}
```

and i add in User models like this

```
 public function getNameDaysAttribute()
{
    return $this->nama . ' - ' . $this->cuti;
}
```

and this view i add this :

```
           <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"> Nama Pegawai <span class="required">*</span></label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <select name="user_id" id="user_id" class="form-control">
                        @foreach($users as $id => $nama )
                        <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $nama }} </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

and having error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name_days' ,,

how i can use this **getNameDaysAttribute()** ??

Comment: Does your table users contains column named "name_days"?

Comment: no , i dont have table name_days . i think this name_days is new variable to save name+days ?

Comment: i follow this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188577/laravel-pluck-multiple-columns?rq=1)

Comment: "save name+days" => you mean to retrive.

Comment: yes , open this link and you will understand i mean

Comment: Instead of using raw Query try User::whereIn('roles_id',[1,3])->pluck('name_days','id'); see if it works

Comment: nono , didnt work .

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('roles_id',[1,3])->pluck('name_days','id');
```

to

```
$users = User::whereIn('roles_id',[1,3]))->pluck('name_days','id');
```

As you can only pluck the data from collection after it is loaded. Accessor function will work with the model.

Comment: didnt work to , this error is same Unknown column 'full_name' in 'field list'

Comment: I've tried it and found that accessors works with eloquent models only..please check the answer.

Comment: you miss a ')' . its solved now with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188577/laravel-pluck-multiple-columns?rq=1